# after compiling sass using laravel mix only webkit is shown

Tags: css, laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I've used the following scss code for mixin but after compilation -moz- and -o- vendor prefixes are not shown in compiled css file.

```
@mixin transition($move) {

     -webkit-transition: $move;
      -moz-transition: $move;
      -o-transition: $move;
      transition: $move;
    }

    a {
      &:hover, &:focus {
        color: $brand-color;
      }
      @include transition(all 0.2s linear);
    }
```

after compiling using mix :

```
a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #4676fa;
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because laravel uses `autoprefixer` to add/remove vendor prefixes based on the browser version limit. Almost every browser now supports `transition`.

You can see transition support [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=transition).

So, removing useless code reduces the bundle size.

And if you really want to support older browsers then set this configuration.

#### For Laravel Mix (Latest)

Add this code on top of your `webpack.mix.js`.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.options({
    postCss: [
        require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: ['last 40 versions'],
        })
    ]
});

...
...
```

#### For Laravel Elixir

Add this code on top of your `gulpfile.js`

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.css.autoprefix.options.browsers = ['last 40 versions'];

...
...
```